# Does C have references?

Tags: c, reference

Does C have references? i.e. as in C++ :

```
void foo(int &i)
```

Answer (score 87):

No, it doesn't. It has *pointers*, but they're not quite the same thing.

In particular, all arguments in C are passed by value, rather than pass-by-reference being available as in C++. Of course, you can sort of *simulate* pass-by-reference via pointers:

```
void foo(int *x)
{
    *x = 10;
}

...

int y = 0;
foo(&y); // Pass the pointer by value
// The value of y is now 10
```

For more details about the differences between pointers and references, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/difference-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c). (And please don't ask me, as I'm not a C or C++ programmer :)

Comment: @Martin: It won't be for long ;)

Comment: @Martin, had the exact same thought

Answer (score 24):

Conceptually, C has references, since pointers reference other objects.

Syntactically, C does not have references as C++ does.

Comment: Wrong, conceptually pointers and references are absolutely different. Pointer is an algebraic data type of null and a reference. Reference is just that, reference. The implication is type safety — it can be immediately seen if a function ever meant getting a null argument or not.

Comment: @sbi well, you could probably say that a null pointer references an object located at memory address `0`, though this implies that standard says nothing about null pointers — I do not know whether it's true. In any case there's a widely established practice to use a null value to mean specifically "the pointer does not reference anything", up to the point I doubt on even existence of a code that uses null to actually reference the null address, perhaps if exploits. IOW even if standard does not treat null pointers in any special way, *conceptually* a null pointer does not reference anything.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: So a pointer is a nullable reference. _Shrug._ That doesn't prevent pointers, _in general_, from being references.

Comment: @sbi okay, now, "nullable reference" is a thing distinct from just a "reference", because the later ensures not ever getting a null at compile time, whereas the former forces to make runtime checks *(or to just hope nobody passed a null)*.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: Did you just say _<adjective>_ references are not references? So a _long_ leg is not a leg? A _red_ carpet is not a carpet? _Snort._ You seem to be stuck with the syntactic definition of "reference" in C++, and fail to see the concept behind it. _HAND._

Comment: @sbi I've used your term to avoid confusion. For some reason it didn't work out. My term for the matter is "algebraic data type of null and reference" *(or less in use but my personal preference "coproduct of null and reference")*, and you can't substitute null → long and reference → leg, and still get something sensible.