# c-code reference to a struct

Tags: c, pass-by-reference

I'm a rather experience C++ programmer, but with (pure!?) C-code I am sometimes struggling, especially when I haven't used it in a while. Can someone give me a hint on why the code below is not working? Compiler says:

```
syntax error : missing ')' before '&'
```

complaining about the line that has the printItem-signature. How I can make it work? Is the only option to change the printItem-signature to:

```
void printItem(const struct structItem *const item)
{   
    printf("age: %i, price: %i", item->age, item->price);
}
```

Or is there another way, that would allow me to keep the signature as it is below? Also, ...I didn't use the more convenient "typedef" notation for the struct, because I remember some issues with that - possibly in this context. If anyone could shed some light on all this, I would be very thankful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct structItem {
    int age;
    int price;
};

void printItem(const struct structItem &item)
{   
    printf("age: %i, price: %i", item.age, item.price);
}

int main()
{
    struct structItem item;
    item.age = 1;
    item.price = 200;

    printItem(item);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the C code isn't working?  Is it not compiling, or faulting, or giving a wrong answer?

Comment: Oh, it's not compiling. I'll edit the text. Sorry.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin: It's a C program, trying to use `&` to denote a reference. Do you really have to ask what's not working?

Comment: i dont think C has a pass by reference so it'll have to be passed by pointer

Comment: @ruakh Forgive me for assuming that the question referred to *both* forms of the `printItem` function, both with the double-`const` pointer and with the reference.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin: Well, the question explicitly stated otherwise; but I can't pretend that *I*'ve never missed part of a question, so yes, I forgive you for doing so. :-P

Comment: @ruakh I understand why you might say that, but I made my comment *before* the edit that added the compiler error message.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin: Sorry, but you *don't* understand. The question explicitly asks -- and has *always* explicitly asked -- if the only fix is to change from the method signature with `&` to the method signature with `*`. It's obvious why the version with `&` wasn't working, and you had no basis for assuming that the `*` wasn't working, because the OP was explicitly asking if it was the *only* way that *would* work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The References are C++ syntax. In pure C you can only use **call-by-reference** with Pointers.

```
void printItem(const struct structItem* const item) {
    printf("age: %i, price: %i", item->age, item->price);
}
```

And be carefull with the function-call. You need to call it with the adress of the structure.

```
struct structItem item;
item.age = 1;
item.price = 200;

printItem(&item);
```

Comment: Danke Jan. You were the first and the answers is most accurate! But thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 4):

In C, you must pass by pointers so you would define `printItem` like this:

```
void printItem(struct structItem *item)
{
    printf("age: %i, price: %i", item->age, item->price);
}
```

To call it, give it the pointer.  E.g.:

```
printItem(&item);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
    struct structItem item;
    item.age = 1;
    item.price = 200;

    printItem(item);
```

At this point, you're passing the *entire structure* to the `printItem()` function. The compiler will (semantically, if not actually) *copy* the structure into temporary storage for your function. If you want to pass the *address* of the `item` structure, amend the call:

```
    printItem(&item);
```

You'll need to amend the prototype for `printItem()` anyway, as this is not legal C:

```
void printItem(const struct structItem &item)
```

GCC throws an error:

```
$ make item
cc     item.c   -o item
item.c:8:40: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
```

Change the `&` to `*` in the function prototype, to declare that the function takes a *pointer to a `structItem`*, amend the function to use `->` to access structure members through a pointer, and the full program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct structItem {
    int age;
    int price;
};

void printItem(const struct structItem *item)
{
    printf("age: %i, price: %i", item->age, item->price);
}

int main()
{
    struct structItem item;
    item.age = 1;
    item.price = 200;

    printItem(&item);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

References aren't part of the C syntax, so you'll have to change it to the `void printItem(const struct structItem *const item)` signature you gave in the question, and change the call accordingly, i.e. `printItem(&item);`

Even Jon Skeet says so: [Does C have references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305673/does-c-have-references)

Answer (score 0):

With a struct that small, you might as well pass by value:

```
void printItem(struct structItem item) {
    printf("age: %i, price: %i\n", item.age, item.price);
}
```

This is faster since no dereferencing is required, and passing by value makes it clear that the item will not be modified.

Comment: In this particular context I agree. However I just made up this example to narrow down the problem. In my real example the struct is MUCH bigger.

Answer (score -1):

The problem that appears to be causing the build break is

```
void printItem(const struct structItem *const item)
```

There is no reason to use the `const` keyword twice; in fact, it's illegal.  Even with the standards compliance cranked way up, I can still compile

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct structItem {
    int age;
    int price;
};

void printItem(const struct structItem *item) {
    printf("age: %i, price: %i\n", item->age, item->price);
}

int main(void) {
    struct structItem item;
    item.age = 10;
    item.price = 100;

    printItem(&item);
    return 0;
}
```

no problem, and the program prints

```
age: 10, price: 100
```

as expected.

Comment: Hm. I don't think using the const keyword twice is a problem. It assures that I don't redirect the pointer inside the function. I just tried it. With the second const, it won't allow me to redirect the pointer. That's what I want, and it works fine.