# How to make a mutable reference to an immutable value

Tags: rust, pass-by-reference, mutable

I'm just beginning to learn a little Rust and am very intrigued by the concept of mutability of variables.

I'm trying to write something very similar to this C++ program.

```
#include <cstdio>

void do_something(int &var) {
   var++;
}

int main() {

    int a = 3;
    int b = a;
    printf("a is %d and b is %d\n", a, b);
    do_something(b);
    printf("a is %d and b is %d\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

I expect to see:

> a is 3 and b is 3
>
> a is 3 and b is 4

The idea is that the pass-by-reference renders `b` mutable, but `a` is not mutable.

Here's how I would assume to write this program in Rust:

```
fn main() {
    let a: i32 = 3;
    let b: &mut i32 = &a;

    println!("a is {} and b is {}", a, b);
    do_something(b);
    println!("a is {} and b is {}", a, b);
}

fn do_something(var: &mut i32) {
    (*var)+=1;
}
```

However, I get errors due to mismatched mutability.

> error: mismatched types:
>
> expected `&mut i32`,
>       found `&i32`
>
> (values differ in mutability) [E0308]

Are there ways to secure this pass-by-reference style in Rust without `::New`? My guess is I could use `.clone()`, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Last I checked, [C doesn't have references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305673/does-c-have-references). Are you sure you aren't using a C++ compiler and treating your code as C++?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You’re misunderstanding what the code is doing. Here is the *actual* equivalent code:

```
fn main() {
    let a: i32 = 3;
    let mut b = a;

    println!("a is {} and b is {}", a, b);
    do_something(&mut b);
    println!("a is {} and b is {}", a, b);
}

fn do_something(var: &mut i32) {
    *var += 1;
}
```

`b` is not, in your C code, a reference of any form; it has absolutely no connection with `a`. It’s just that C allows you to pass a value and have it infer that it must take a reference to it, while Rust is very sensibly explicit about such things, and so you need to write `&mut b` rather than just `b` to pass a mutable reference to `do_something`. The `mut b` earlier on just makes the `b` slot mutable, allowing you to mutate the value inside it (without it, you won’t be able to create a mutable reference to `b`).