# Why is the output of the following program 2 97 and not 2 2?

Tags: c

In the following code why doesn't the address of j gets overwritten in p when we call the foo function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
        int main()
        {
            int i = 97, *p = &i;
            foo(&i);
            printf("%d ", *p);
        }
        void foo(int *p)
        {
            int j = 2;
            p = &j;
            printf("%d ", *p);
        }
```

Comment: the `p` in `main` and the `p` in `foo` are two totally different variables in totally different scopes.

Comment: He needs to add a * and remove a &, but figuring out which is probably the reason the homework was assigned :o)

Comment: `foo(&i);` passes the address of `main` `i` to `foo()`.  `foo(int *p)` receives that address as `p` and then assigns `foo` `p` to the address of the local `j` effectively ignoring whatever was passed into `foo`.

Answer (score 4):

You are printing with `foo` - which sets `p` to `2`,  then you call a print to `p`, which is still set to `97` in that scope.  `foo` does not set `p` globally.

Answer (score 2):

Because `p` in `main` is another variable than `p` in the function. Consequently, even if `p` is changed inside the function, the value of `p` in `main` is still the same and still points to 97.

In more details:

```
    int main()
    {
        int i = 97, *p = &i;  // i is 97 and p points to i
        foo(&i);
        printf("%d ", *p);    // This prints what p points to, i.e. 97
    }
    void foo(int *p)
    {
        int j = 2;   // Here p still points to i in main
        p = &j;      // Now p points to j, i.e. the value 2
        printf("%d ", *p);  // So this prints 2
    }
```

Just to repeat: The important thing is that `p` in `main` and `p` in `foo` are two different variables.

If you want the program to print `2 2` you can change the function to:

```
    void foo(int *p)
    {
        int j = 2;
        *p = j;     // Change this line. This will change i in main
                    // and thereby also the value that p in main points to
        printf("%d ", *p);
    }
```

Comment: p isn't even passed.  It's a reference to i that's passed.  But yeah.

Comment: @JGroven - There is no references in C. But your right - what is passed is the address of `i` which just happens to be the same value that is assigned to `p` in main.

Comment: @4386427 There is no pass-by-reference in C. Yet `&i` can rightly be called a referencing of `i`. `&i` in itself has nothing to do with the function call.

Comment: @chux What to you mean by: "&i in itself has nothing to do with the function call"? It is exactly what is passed to the function.

Comment: The referencing of `i`, done with `&`, results in the address of `i`.  That operation is prior to the function call and so is not part of the function call's pass by value.  It is as if `int *q = &i; foo(q);`  Hence the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100752/why-is-the-output-of-the-following-program-2-97-and-not-2-2/48100828?noredirect=1#comment83176766_48100828) concerning @JGroven "It's a reference to i that's passed".

Comment: @chux Of cause `&i` is evaluated before the function call but to me it is too much nitpicking to state that it is unrelated to `&i` as the value passed is simply the address of `i`. Anyway - C doesn't have references. A pointer is something different than a reference. And a reference is not limited to passing to a function like in "pass by reference"

Comment: @JGroven - As the answers in your link says, there is no such thing as references in C. C passes by value and C doesn't have references locally either. C has pointers which is different from references. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305673/does-c-have-references

Comment: @4386427 TIL and thank you.  Pointers can still be dereferenced, though, which I think leads to a lot of confusion in this semantical matter.

Comment: C spec uses "reference" as [@JGroven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100752/why-is-the-output-of-the-following-program-2-97-and-not-2-2/48100828?noredirect=1#comment83176766_48100828) uses it.  "A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a _reference_
to an entity of the referenced type."

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps:

```
    int main()
    {
        int  i = 97;
        int* p = &i;        // 1. p points to i, i is 97.
        foo(&i);            // 2. Pass the address of i by value.

        printf("%d ", *p);  // 6. Print the value of i as neither p nor i have not changed inside foo().
    }

    // I've renamed the parameter name from p to q for clarity. q is local to
    // foo() only; changes made to q are only visible within foo().
    void foo(int* q)
    {                      // 3. q contains a copy of i's address.
        int j = 2;
        q     = &j;        // 4. q is set to the address of j. 

        printf("%d ", *q); // 5. Print the value of j.
    }
```

If you would have done `*q = 2` inside `foo()` you would have changed `i`'s value to `2`. That's because `q` contains the address of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

The `p` in `main` is a different object in memory than the `p` in `foo`.  Writing to one has no effect on the other.  If you want `foo` to update the value of `p` in `main`, then you must pass a pointer to `p`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 97, *p = &i;
    foo(&p);
    printf("%d ", *p);
}

void foo(int **p)
{
    int j = 2;
    *p = &j;
    printf("%d ", **p);
}
```

**WARNING** - doing this will invoke *undefined behavior*, since `p` will point to an object that no longer exists - once `foo` exits, `j` no longer exists, and `p` will be an *invalid* pointer.  You *may* get the output you expect, or you may not.

In order for a function to write to a parameter, you must pass a pointer to that parameter:

```
void foo( T *ptr )
{
  *ptr = new_value(); // updates the thing ptr points to
}

void bar( void )
{
  T var;              // var is an instance of T
  foo( &var );        // have foo update the value of var
}
```

This is true for *any non-array type `T`*, including pointer types.  If we replace `T` with the pointer type `P *`, we get

```
void foo( P * *ptr )
{
  *ptr = new_value(); // updates the thing ptr points to
}

void bar( void )
{
  P * var;            // var is an instance of P *
  foo( &var );        // have foo update the value of var
}
```

The semantics are exactly the same - the only thing that's changed is that `var` starts out as a pointer type.

Things get weird with array types, which we're not going to go into quite yet.